# How to send Checkbox checked Values to Formcollection Parameter in controller from aspx view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

```
  <asp:CheckBoxList ID="checkboxlistCustomerSubCategoryTypeID" ClientIDMode="Static" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" RepeatColumns="1" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Flow" TextAlign="Right" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>Very Important Patron</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Volunteer</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
                <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cvcheckboxlistCustomerSubCategoryTypeID" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateCheckboxList" ErrorMessage="Customer SubCategory Type" Display="None"></asp:CustomValidator>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCustomerSubCategoryTypeID" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Value="" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnAddEditCustomerContact" runat="server" Text="CustomerContact &raquo;"
                    CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClientClick="UpdateCheckList()" />

            <script lang="javascript">
               function UpdateCheckList() {
                                        var ids = "";
                                        $('#checkboxlistCustomerSubCategoryTypeID').find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                                            if (this.checked) {
                                                if (ids != "") {
                                                    ids = ids + ","
                                                }
                                                ids = ids + $(this).val();
                                            }
                                        });
                                        //assign set value to hidden field   
                                        $('#hdnCustomerSubCategoryTypeID').val(ids);

                                    }
               </script>


         [HttpPost]
                [ValidateInput(false)]
                public ActionResult AddCustomerContact(FormCollection collection)
                {

        }
```

I want to post checkbox checked values on button click to controller but I am not Getting values of checked listitems in Controller from hiddenfield id.Kindy Help me with That

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to post it in JS script:

1, remove `UpdateCheckList()` from button,

2, change script like this:

```
<script lang="javascript">
function UpdateCheckList() {
    var ids = "";
    $('#checkboxlistCustomerSubCategoryTypeID').click(function() {
            this.each(function() {
                if (this.checked) {
                    if (ids != "") {
                        ids = ids + ","
                    }
                    ids = ids + $(this).val();
                }
                //assign set value to hidden field   
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/YourController/AddCustomerContact/',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        data: ids
                    },
                    datatype: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log('success');
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        console.log('error');
                    }
                });
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: It Worked but to assign value to hidden field I used     //assign set value to hidden field   
                            $('#hdnCustomerSubCategoryTypeID').val(ids);

                        }

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach,

```
function UpdateCheckList() {
    var ids = "";
    $.each($("input[type=checkbox]:checked"), function(){
        ids.push($(this).attr('value'));
    });
    //assign set value to hidden field   
    $('#hdnPOSAccessIDs').val(ids.join(","));
}
```